# webservice call is not working in android browser

Tags: android, web-services, header, android-browser

wen i deploy my web service on server, its working good in Internet Explorer but not working in mozilla and chrome.
According to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin) i add this header to my serveer

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

but still its not working.
then i got the solution and add another headers like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin
Access-Control-Max-Age
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
Access-Control-Allow-Headers
```

then its working good in all browsers on my desktop, **but** when i try to this web service using android browser, its showing me undefined error.
now what can i do to solve this problem.
Help me.

Comment: undefined what? The error will usually tell you which variable is undefined.
If it is something from request scope check if that variable is named differently android

Comment: when i call service, if any error it fail to run then its call this function : 

    function OnError(request, status, error) {
   alert(error);
        }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution guys.
i have deployed service on server but was calling it by local server link..
by just giving right link got the output..
thanx guys.